# React/Non React Hybrid App IE10 Performance Issues

Tags: reactjs

I have an admittedly weird question to ask. We are in the process of migrating an existing application over to react. Due to some limitations of the legacy code we are dealing with, the majority of our users are on IE11 in IE10 compatibility mode. We are running into an issue with fairly large doms where the rest of the non react application has experienced maybe a 20% rendering time increase with react not actually rendering anything on the page (though it is still loaded in memory). This doesn't quite make sense to me since i thought that react only keeps track of its own trees. Is there anything else that react might be doing globally that might cause these types of performance problems? I've dug through performance session traces in IE and nothing really jumps out at me as being executed on the react side. Ideally we'd have smaller doms I realize, but we're dealing with some legacy code and that's not an immediate option.

Comment: reactjs makes the project a Single Page Application so in essence the whole site is now a react project. With that said I am guessing that an IE compatibility issue is taxing the client cpu somewhere.

Comment: Yeah the compatibility issues are my thought as well except I don't see any console errors or js from the react scripts on the page in any of the stack traces in the performance profiler. Not sure where else to check for where the issues might be coming from.

Comment: It might just be IE and not reactjs at all. Can you remove/replace the reactjs portion and test IE site performance on its own?

Comment: I have two scenarios that I've tested:

1. the app without react referenced or loaded in the app at all
2. the app with react loaded in the app (but no react elements rendered in the DOM)

2 ends up taking about 10-20% longer than 1.

Comment: I supose that a react state change could trigger the browser to process alot of data and that could be the source of the slowdown. This could happen without endering the DOM. Maybe look for something like that?

Comment: Could something trigger a React state change if no React code has been executed?

Comment: We've done a little more trial and error testing and if react-dom isn't loaded in memory the problem seems to go away (but not if react isn't loaded in memory). That likely makes sense since that's where a lot of the event listening logic is, but I'm still confused why it would be affecting things if nothing is mounted.